# Add notification to Windows notification center without displaying it on screen

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, windows, notifications

I am building an Electron app featuring a custom Notification feature where html5 divs appear and disappear as needed on a frameless, transparent, always-on-top window.

It works great, but: I still like the Windows notification center itself, and would like to have the option to see the past notifications there, without actually displaying them on screen with the HTML5 api.

I have tried:

- Looking into the HTML5 api for an option to not show a notification, or to .hide() it right away: no luck. The only method that comes close is .close(), and it removes the notification from the center as well.
- Looking into packages like [node-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier), but none of the used notification dependencies offer a way to completely hide a notification.

While I mentioned Node, I will also accept any lower-level API/binding that would allow me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give more info about how your Electron app relates to the Windows notification framework? At the moment it's not clear why your Electron app can't simply exclude notifications user doesn't want,  such as notifications raised longer ago than say 1 hour ago, or other criteria user can choose to filter on.

Comment: @RegEdit To simplify: Windows 10 lets you choose to "Show Notification Banners" or not in global settings. I want to have this choice on a per-notification basis. When a notification comes, I want to be able to display it or not on screen, but it should always still go in the Notification Center archive (bottom-right button) whether it showed or not.

Comment: did you try with inbuilt node Notification API?

Comment: I gave this a shot and had been playing around with the repos https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps and https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-notifications. It turned out they also seem to be using the Notification API, and there is also NodeRT in there as well. I was thinking maybe in NodeRT the Windows.Ui.Notifications classes would have some luck but I wasn't able to find anything of merit at least for now. But if you haven't checked out those repos r @nodert-win10-au/windows.ui.notifications they could be helpful!

Comment: Also, I had just discovered that Notification content and metadata on Windows 10 is all stored here: `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications\wpndatabase.db`, and is just a SQL Lite database. Has 8 tables in there. I'd think that if you were able to find some was to interact with that DB, given there is the permission to do so, you could easily just have some SQL queries to add in the notification. That would then solve you problem of getting them stored in the Action/Notification center and not displaying on the front end.

Comment: @treckstar This is all useful research, thanks. I am digging into those, but if by then you manage to get a PoC showing how to effectively push a notification into the centre, without displaying it on-screen, you may post an answer that I will accept and award the bounty to.

Comment: @treckstar A combination of the NodeRT windows.ui.notifications binding, along with the suppressPopup argument in the official Windows api here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.suppresspopup , would likely provide what we need.

Comment: Yeah most definitely seems promising. I keep getting some garbanzo error while trying to require the packages that require the Notifications.UI stuff, and it seems like an electron thing maybe... Essentially my preloader.js never gets in because of allowRendererProcessReuse, which isn't working. This is my first time ever using electron so maybe I can get it working in a bit. Edit, forgot about Electron Fiddle, that may help solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [@treckstar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72167251/1712345) in comments, I have found a way to do what I wanted using:

- [NodeRT](https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT)
- The [ToastNotification.SuppressPopup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.suppresspopup) attribute

Despite a handful of troubles building NodeRT and using electron-rebuild, here's a working PoC:

```
const { XmlDocument } = require('@nodert-win10-rs4/windows.data.xml.dom');
const {
  ToastNotification,
  ToastNotificationManager
} = require('@nodert-win10-rs4/windows.ui.notifications');

const localImage = path.join(__dirname, 'icon.png');
const template = `
  <toast launch="app-defined-string">
    <visual>
      <binding template="ToastGeneric">
        <image id="1" placement="appLogoOverride" hint-crop="circle" src="${localImage}"/>
      </binding>
    </visual>
  </toast>
`;

const xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.loadXml(template);

const toast = new ToastNotification(xml);
const notifier = ToastNotificationManager.createToastNotifier("com.myapp.testnotif");
toast.suppressPopup = true;
notifier.show(toast);
```

May this help whoever comes across the same highly-specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [@MadWard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72165410/1712345) shows in the PoC, the `suppressPopup` key is really the main player of the solution.

As I was going through tons of examples and electron code I kept hitting roadblocks due to random SDK versions and libraries of things I had installed. For example, the package [electron-windows-notifications](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-notifications), which uses NodeRT was failing to load my `preload.js` because the Windows 10 SDK I had installed (build 15063) needed `nodert-win10-cu` instead of what was being used in most solutions by default `nodert-wind10-au`.

| SDK | Known As | Windows Version | npm Scope |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Windows 10, Build 17134 | April 2018 Update (Redstone 4) | 1803 | [npmjs.com/org/nodert-win10-rs4](https://www.npmjs.com/org/nodert-win10-rs4) |
| Windows 10, Build 16299 | Fall Creators Update (Redstone 3) | 1709 | [npmjs.com/org/nodert-win10-rs3](https://www.npmjs.com/org/nodert-win10-rs3) |
| Windows 10, Build 15063 | Creators Update (Redstone 2) | 1703 | [npmjs.com/org/nodert-win10-cu](https://www.npmjs.com/org/nodert-win10-cu) |
| Windows 10, Build 14393 | Anniversary Update (Redstone 1) | 1607 | [npmjs.com/org/nodert-win10-au](https://www.npmjs.com/org/nodert-win10-au) |
| Windows 10, Build 10586 | Threshold 2 | 1511 | [npmjs.com/~nodert-win10](https://www.npmjs.com/%7Enodert-win10) |

> EDIT: I forgot to include the more specific steps I took getting `electron-windows-notifications` dependency files [on this GitHub issue here.](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-notifications/issues/33#issuecomment-1120373864) Basically everything from `Python`, broken `node-gyp`, and missing `.winmd` files.

Lastly Electron 14+ and NodeRT have an issue where you will need to make sure to have `app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false` and like the readme file says, to make sure this is running in the `main.js` file.

Hopefully this helps someone along the way, as I had never used Electron before until today and had learned a ton thanks to other peoples help.